# How can I put a minipage that fits to the actual line width inside of a TikZ Node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, minipage, calculations

## Question

I would like to put a minipage environment inside of a tikz node. I know this is done already with the align=left command, but if you set a minimum width of the node to \linewidth, then the text is left aligned, but surrounded by white space padding (depending on how much text you include)

## Problem

When I set the width of the minipage environment to \linewidth, minipage grabs the width of the line on a page instead of the width of the node.

## Sample Code

```
\newcommand{\warning}[1]{%
% Define box and box title style
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [align=left,draw=red, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt,maximum width=\linewidth]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=red, text=white,rounded corners]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
        \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
        #1
        \end{minipage}
        };
    \node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Note:};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
```

Adapted code from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/

Comment: the node does not have a width initially (it is an hbox that is just set the natural width of the content. If you set text width = ... it has a natural width (and it's already a minipage

Comment: Actually, its a \parbox, not a minipage.  It does not like having \par inside! ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,showframe}
\tikzset{mybox/.style = {text width=\dimexpr\linewidth-20pt-\pgflinewidth\relax,align=justify,draw=red,
                very thick, rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt},
        fancytitle/.style ={fill=red, text=white,rounded corners}
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
        \lipsum[1]
        };
    \node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Note:};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With an explicit `minipage` as requested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,showframe}
\tikzset{mybox/.style = {align=center,draw=red,
                very thick, rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt},
        fancytitle/.style ={fill=red, text=white,rounded corners}
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-20pt-\pgflinewidth\relax}
          \lipsum[1]
        \end{minipage}%
        };
    \node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Note:};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: I would suggest to not reinvent the wheel: `mdframed` and `tcolorbox` does this job better :)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: I was about to write: But why don't you use `tcolorbox`? and then you commented! :) I will add a `tcolorbox` version in some time.

Comment: @ Harish: `:-)`

Comment: No, not like that. I asked for a minipage inside of TikZ node.

Comment: mdframed and tcolorbox are great! I would like to know how to do this on my own nonetheless. I can control every detail this way.

Comment: @macmadness86 It is a `minipage`. Do you want an explicit `minipage`?

Comment: You're right Harish. My mistake. But if an explicit minipage is possible, I would also like to know how that is possible. Thanks!

Comment: @macmadness86 Right. What should be the width then? Should it vary?

Comment: The width should be the text width of the node. If the text width is set to \linewidth, shouldn't I be able to use \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}?

Comment: +1 Thanks, I knew it had something to do with the \pgflinewidth!

Comment: One more question since you obviously know what you're doing...is the 20pt subtraction from line width due to the innersep=10pt, which of course applies to the padding on both horizontal sides of the node?

Comment: @macmadness86 Yes, 10pt on left and 10pt on right so 20 pt. And `\pgflinewidth` is half for left and half for right side.